# How to get depth frame texture in Kinect sdk 2.0?

Tags: kinect

In Kinect sdk 1.0, there is method called `NuiImageFrameGetDepthImagePixelFrameTexture`. But I can't find it in sdk 2.0.

Comment: it's only available in Kinect for Windows 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8

Comment: Which method is the alternative version? Also, I don't know how to lock the frame data in sdk 2.0. Thanks in advance.